# NSManagedObjectContext? does not have a member named 'executeFetchRequest'

Tags: nsmanagedobjectcontext, executefetchrequest

I'm trying to convert my objective-c code:

NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

to swift:

```
 var objects : NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
```

but it doesn't seem to work that way. Any ideas on what to do?